# Mklink to a network share, disconnect results in "location is not available"

Tags: windows-7, mklink

I've used mklink in Windows 7 to map a local folder to a network share (the iMac sitting next to me on the gigabit hub at my desk). However, when the iMac goes to sleep, the linked folder becomes unavailable on my PC. I would expect this, and this is fine, but when I wake the mac back up, Windows doesn't refresh the status of the folder. How can I get it to do so?

Comment: Did you mklink a hard link, or a soft link?

Comment: I just did mklink /d